# SQlite Query select string date today or less than

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

Im having problem in query 
i cannot get the proper result dates i want
I need to get all the date from today or less than date today

can you help me or give me right query to use

for example this is **mytable**

```
id(number) datestring(string)
1          02/06/2019
2          02/06/2019 
3          02/14/2019
4          02/04/2019
5          03/17/2019
```

query i use: **SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE  datestring  <=  date('now')**

expected result is
 
`id(number) datestring(string)
    1          02/06/2019
    2          02/06/2019 
    4          02/04/2019`

Thank you for helping

Comment: You should store your date values in a format understood by sqlite: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html Of course comparing a `mm/dd/yyyy` format string to a `yyyy-mm-dd` one isn't going to work right.

Comment: Also read https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#date_and_time_datatype

Comment: ah hmmm okay let me try it . am also confuse on my format and datetype . :) be rigthback

Comment: ok decide to adjust my code to proper format. :) thanks @Shawn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are encountering is that date('now') will return 2019-02-06 , as such as all rows in the table start with 0  and that this is less than 2.

You either need to convert on of the dates to be in the same format as the other or use the same format when storing the data.

SQLite itself has various date format that can be recognised and used and it is advisable to utilise one of these as reduces necessary complexity.

> Time Strings A time string can be in any of the following formats:
>
> ```
> YYYY-MM-DD
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
> YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
> HH:MM
> HH:MM:SS
> HH:MM:SS.SSS
> now
> DDDDDDDDDD
> ```

[SQL As Understood By SQLite - Date And Time Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html)

The following is a solution that could be used to convert the **datestring** column within the query :-

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE substr(datestring,7,4)||'-'||substr(datestring,1,2)||'-'||substr(datestring,4,2) <= date('now');
```

The following could be used to convert the existing data to a recognised format :-

```
UPDATE mytable SET datestring = substr(datestring,7,4)||'-'||substr(datestring,1,2)||'-'||substr(datestring,4,2);
```

This could be followed by your original query

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE datestring <= date('now');
```